# Resizing the actual Tabs in a (Godot) TabContainer, is it possible?

Tags: godot

Given some Tabs in a Godot TabContainer, I'd like to resize the actual Tab-elements (not the container they're a part of.

[image]

Given that so many things are customizable, it seems like these would be too, but so far I haven't found how. The question [How to resize a Tab](https://godotengine.org/qa/34899/how-to-resize-tab-button), sounded promising, but the "Custom Style" that it referred to, doesn't seem to exist - or at least didn't appear in a help-search.

Update: The given answer got me closer. There's a lot of variables, it's definitely not production-ready, but it does at least, appear *possible* to modify the size of Tabs. And just realized that one of the variables is Content-Margin, I had edited just Margin, to create this picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn about themes in Godot to resize your elements.

In the editor select the TabContainer, in the Inspector search the Theme property, and in the Theme variable below you can load a theme or create a new one for your project.

If you create a new theme there will be a file with a extension ".tres". Double click on that file to edit the aspect of different elements for your project.

I will try to add more detail. If you edit your theme file ( .tres), with the Type: TabContainer, you can override the multiple StyleBox of the Tab. I tried with the tab_fg, click on the plus sign, later in [Empty], New StyleBoxFlat, click on the new StyleBox Flat created in the field, and edit it in the Inspector. Edit the Expand Margin values, and also the Content Margin values.

You can also increase the font size, overriding the font with a New Dynamic Font, selecting it and editting it in the Inspector, in settings-> Size.

You can find further info in the [UI tutorials section on GUI skinning](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/ui/gui_skinning.html)

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? I'm looking at the Theme and the Tab setting, but don't see any option to actually make it larger. Things like Font, Margin, etc are changeable, but apparently not size.

Comment: I will try to add more detail. If you edit your theme file ( .tres), with the Type: TabContainer, you can override the multiple StyleBox of the Tab. I tried with the tab_fg, click on the plus sign, later in [Empty], New StyleBoxFlat, click on the new StyleBox Flat created in the field, and edit it in the Inspector. Edit the Expand Margin values, and also the Content Margin values.

Comment: You can also increase the font size, overriding the font with a New Dynamic Font, selecting it and editting it in the Inspector, in settings-> Size.

Comment: That did it. I haven't got it exactly correct, there are a lot of variables to tweak, but at least the tab-size increased, thanks. Also a minor note, you can edit your Answer, could put those comments *in* the Answer.